# TKProf (Oracle event 10046) on Spring Boot/JDBC

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jdbc, oracle10g, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to start oracle tracing through invoking direct JDBC calls. I'm obtaining my connection from Spring (boot/jdbc). Then I run the TKProf commands through statements... execute the query and print to the log.

The 3 statements below are returning *false*. If I use this same statements through Intellij's console I will get the intended results and my *.trc file is properly generated.

```
try (final Connection connection = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource)) {
        log.debug(query);
        final Long maxCount = findMaxCount();
        boolean traceIdSet = connection.createStatement().execute("ALTER SESSION SET TRACEFILE_IDENTIFIER = '" + traceId + "'");
        boolean traceEnabled = connection.createStatement().execute("ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10046 trace name context forever, level 8'");
        final PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        map(consumer, stmt.executeQuery(query));
        boolean traceIdOff = connection.createStatement().execute("ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10046 trace name context off'");
        log.debug("|" + traceIdSet + "|" + traceEnabled + "|" + traceIdOff + "| ____________________ DONE __________________________");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error("Error Performing the Query", e);
    }
```

It has to be something in my configuration... I mean, java thin driver can do it because I can do it over the IDE... so I have to be missing some other stuff, maybe a Spring Boot convention that I should change.

Could you please help, any input is valuable.

Thanks!

Comment: False is correct; [from the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute-java.lang.String-) it returns "true if the first result is a ResultSet object; false if it is an update count or there are no results". There are no results from an `alter`. Is the query actually running, and are you sure you're looking in the right place for the trace file?

Comment: The next step would be to get rid of the proxy connection and call the `ALTER` statement with the real Oracle connection. See [getTargetConnection](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceUtils.html#getTargetConnection-java.sql.Connection-)

Comment: Thank you both... I'll try the getTargetConneciton and post back.

Comment: Didn´t worked either. puf.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, the real issue was that I wasn't getting proper response from...

> SELECT value FROM v$diag_info

Where I couldn't found the trace file, but only some others...

Nevertheless the trc files are in place, so there is no problem with Spring Boot/JDBC for enabling TKProf.